# How to make a plotly graph in R with adjustable zoom for axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I'm using ggplot to make a couple of line graphs on one plot.
I'm then using

```
ggplotly(plot_name)
```

to turn this into a plotly object.

[image]

When I view the plotly/node.js object, and I unselect trace 1, so I only see trace 0, the scale stays the same. Plotly has some zoom buttons in the top right, but I'm after a way to add a slider or similar widget in, so that I can manually adjust the y axis to stretch it, and expand how much of the chart the blue line takes up (ideally with more granular y ticks filled in). Is this possible in plotly? Thanks

PS I've looked at something like this:
https://plotly.com/python/range-slider/
but I'm not sure how to implement it with a ggplot object

Answer (score 0):

*Note - after re-reading your question, it's not clear to me whether your question is actually about implementing a rangeslider, but rather, the way that the axis is scaled. The default behavior of a plotly plot generated in the manner below matches what you described - it looks like `ggplotly()` may be setting an explicit y axis range that overrides the default automatic re-scaling when a trace is added or removed.*

While `ggplotly()` is certainly a great tool in the toolbox, using `plotly` package functions directly allows users to leverage the full capabilities of the library. Sometimes, when it comes to layout modifications, it works to apply things after the fact - it might be as simple as passing your ggplot object to an extra `layout()` call for rendering.

```
plot_name |> layout(xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(type = "date")))
```

However, this is a case where you will be better served by using the plotly package functions directly. An example of implementing range sliders with the R package is provided in the [plotly documentation site](https://plotly.com/r/range-slider/), but a more succinct example is as follows:

```
data.frame(Date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-01-01"), to = as.Date("2022-12-31"),length.out = 400),
           y = sin(seq_len(400)/5)* 4 + rnorm(400),
           y2 = sin(seq_len(400)/10) * 2 + rnorm(400)) |> 
  plot_ly() |> 
  add_lines(x = ~Date, y = ~y, name = "Series 1",
            line = list(color = "red")) |> 
  add_lines(x = ~Date, y = ~ y2, name = "Series 2",
            line = list(color = "blue")) |> 
  layout(xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(type = "date")))
```

[image: Graph with range slider]